# counterexample for Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The Dominated Convergence Theorem is as follows:
[image]

What if the sequence $\left\{f_n \right\} \notin L^1$? Could someone provide a counterexample as to why the theorem wouldn't hold? Thanks!

Comment: If this is so, then the second condition could not hold?

Comment: If the functions $f_n$ are not in $L^1$ the integrals $\int f_n$ are not even defined hence the theorem becomes pointless.

Answer (score 2):

If you require $|f_{n}|\le g, a.e , g\in L^{1},\forall n$, then you automatically showed $f_{n}\in L^{1}$ as well since $\int |f_{n}|\le \int g\le c$. So this cannot happen. And if $f_{n}$ are not Lesbegue integrable, then I think Did's comment is helpful.